# Neo4J Cypher - SET data ONCE after processing it in a loop

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm working on a short **homomorphic** query which aims to transform certain letters of a string input, into other fixed letters.

For instance, I would like all the letters 'A' to be transformed in 'E', and all the 'E' to be turned into 'O'.
I **can't** use sequentials native replace() functions, because the following would happen:

```
    Input : LEA
    replace n°1: LEE
    replace n°2: LOO
```

Wished output versus output obtained : `LOE / LOO`

So I decided to process letter by letter, looping over my string caracters. In the below example I transform all the 'E' by 'O':

```
MATCH (...stringToReplace..)
UNWIND range(0,size(apoc.text.split(stringToReplace,'',0))-1) AS i
  SET stringToReplace = CASE
    WHEN apoc.text.split(stringToReplace,'',0)[i] = 'E'
      THEN substring(stringToReplace,0,i) + "O" + substring(stringToReplace, i+1, size(apoc.text.split(stringToReplace,'',0))-1)
    ELSE stringToReplace
  END
RETURN stringToReplace
```

**The problem** I encounter is that I'll have as many SET queries as the string has letters. I think that performance-wise, this is pretty lame.

What I would like to have, and I'm not sure it's possible in Cypher, is to modify an aggregating variable inside the loop and **then** SET my data. I tried to use a `WITH` statement before my UNWIND loop but didn't manage to store data inside a var.

***Edit:*** I managed to do a different implementation but it's still return and setting too many times. Even though the end result is right.

```
MATCH (...stringToReplace...)
UNWIND range(0,size(apoc.text.split(stringToReplace,'',0))-1) AS i
    WITH CASE
        WHEN apoc.text.split(stringToReplace,'',0)[i] = 'a'
            THEN substring(stringToReplace,0,i) + "i" + substring(stringToReplace, i+1, size(apoc.text.split(stringToReplace,'',0))-1)
        ELSE stringToReplace
    END AS outputString, stringToReplace
SET stringToReplace = outputString
RETURN stringToReplace
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should convert every character in `stringToReplace`

```
MATCH (...stringToReplace..)
RETURN REDUCE(s = '', c IN split(stringToReplace,'') |
  s + CASE c
      WHEN 'A' THEN 'E'
      WHEN 'E' THEN 'O'
      ELSE c
    END
) as result
```

Just add more `WHEN`/`THEN` clauses to handle all the character conversions needed.

Comment: This works and it's much more elegant than what I was trying to do. Thank you sir !
May I ask if you would have any advice to efficiently handle the lowercases as well ? The easy way would be to go for twice the number of conditions but I wonder if there isn't something cleaner.